# Как расположить с помощью CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы было 4 кликабельных элемента расположенные с помощью CSS Grid Допустим в 1 будет название
"Картинки" 2 - "Музыка" и т.д

Comment: а с чем конкретно проблема? Создание самой сетки или расположение туда элементов?